# QT how to handle a button-press event from the external C++ class

Tags: c++, qt, button, eventhandler, qtcore

I want to write an external C++ class called "buttonHandler", which supports specifically button-click event in Qt, but I don't know how to create a hard link to the objects (buttons) from the "mainContainer" class and simultaneously handle them by the another class. Is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean with external  C++ class?

Comment: Do you understand how Qt signals and slots work?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to separate interface elements (objects) as themselves from the event handler (another .cpp file) - in this case, one external class "buttonHandler" purposely deals only with the button click event, nothing else.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, I roughly understand these mechanics, but I couldn't find anywhere tips how to actually handle an event from the level of the external class.

Comment: The click event is part of the GUI. What you can separate is the logic that is executed when the click is done

Comment: If that's what you want to do, you must create the class that inherits from QObject, creating a slot in it. And then connect the clicked signal of the button with the slot of the new class

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, so as I understand I cannot simply make a link to the objects (buttons), but I have to define this event directly in the "mainContainer" class, the same place where buttons are defined themselves - the post-click functions might be however defined yet in the second class. Seems logic.

Comment: In this link you can find an example of what I say: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/Example

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters). Basically you have an object (derived from `QObject`) that *listens* to the events of other object. It is called **before** the object process its own events. A quick example:

```
bool ButtonPressHandler::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event) {
  if (obj == the_main_container && event->type() == QEvent::MousePress) {
    /* do what ever you have to do */
    return true; // true to stop processing events, false to forward the event
  }

  return false;
}
```

Somewhere on your code you link both:

```
the_main_container->installEventFilter(the_button_press_handler);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but in my case it doesn't work. Perhaps I will have to remodel it from the scratch.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd highly recommend this pattern since it avoids unnecessary inheritance on basic controls as well as allows you to easily _inject_ code. If you have to do it from a non-Qt class you can use a delegate or callback pattern to do it and create the event filtering object in the Qt side.

Comment: @TheInvisibleMan, could you solve this problem or you need further help?

Comment: thank you for your attention, but in the meanwhile I abandoned that project. Sorry for taking your time.